# Here Maps Traffic REST API - Roadways to Lat Lon Location

Tags: here-maps-rest

I'm relatively new to using HERE maps so I apologize in advance if I'm a little off base here. I would like to use the Traffic API and need to somehow get lat lon data to plot on a map.

The request url I am using:

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/flow.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&bbox=30.401579,-97.738369;30.395744,-97.733266&responseattributes=sh%2Cfc

I've found the documentation about the flow response format here:

https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy

however, I am having trouble figuring out how to make this data useful. I see that each roadway has an LI (Unique string identifier for this Linear) and each flow has a TMC PC code but I'm not sure exactly what either of these mean and what I need to do to get more useful location data. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

***UPDATE***
I did find that in the url I can add the param to include response attributes (I've updated the url above). I've used this to as for the SHP attribute which will include an array of arrays of lat lons however I'm still having trouble understanding the format and why it's an array of arrays. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using HERE Map Tiles API? Live traffic tiles have been deprecated in the Traffic API and are now available only on the Map Tiles API.

With Map Tiles API you also have great control over your map, being able to display POIs, truck restrictions and others.

You will have to workout the concept of row/column required by the tiles with your BBox though.